# XDIME for Mobile Applications

Tags: mobile

I'm involved in a project that requires to mobile-enable some previously developed Portlets. The Portlets are deployed in WebSphere Portal, and the container offers a technology called IBM Mobile Portal Accelerator that uses XDIME to render mobile pages according to the device.

I'm trying to document myself in the technology and I'm having a bad time: Google only shows some outdated sites from IBM and even older posts from Volantis, another company involved in the technology (Amazon shows no related books). So... what's the current status of that technology actually? Is has some decent level of adoption?